# Class in AAR file not available in Android Studio

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, aar

I created a library project which I built as an AAR file and later included in another project. It's in the libs folder, and the main gradle.build file includes it: `implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar','*.aar'], dir: 'libs')`

When I try to use classes of this aar file, all of them are available except one class. I initially imagined it could be Proguard, but I even removed Proguard and it is still not available. It's a public class, and it's even there when I decompile the AAR file.

This is the content:

```
package com.onboarding;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.Keep;


/**
 *
 */
@Keep
public class Builder {


    /**
     *
     */
    public static String mainColor = null;
    public static String baseUrl = null;
    public static Class firstActivity = null;
    public static Class onboardingSettingsActivity = null;


    /**
     *
     */
    public static String tosUrl = null;
    public static String privacyUrl = null;
    public static String cookieUrl = null;
    public static String contactsLearnMoreUrl = null;


    /**
     *
     */
    private static Builder builder = null;


    /**
     *
     */
    private Builder() {}


    /**
     *
     */
    public static Builder init() {
        if (builder == null) {
            builder = new Builder();
        }
        return builder;
    }


    /**
     *
     */
    public void start(final Context context) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, Onboarding1.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }


    /**
     *
     */
    public Builder setMainColor(final String color) {
        mainColor = color;
        return this;
    }


    /**
     *
     */
    public Builder setBaseUrl(final String url) {
        baseUrl = url;
        return this;
    }


    /**
     *
     */
    public Builder setFirstActivity(final Class c) {
        firstActivity = c;
        return this;
    }


    /**
     *
     */
    public Builder setOnboardingSettingsActivity(final Class c) {
        onboardingSettingsActivity = c;
        return this;
    }


    /**
     *
     */
    public Builder setTosUrl(final String u) {
        tosUrl = u;
        return this;
    }


    /**
     *
     */
    public Builder setPrivacyUrl(final String u) {
        privacyUrl = u;
        return this;
    }


    /**
     *
     */
    public Builder setCookieUrl(final String u) {
        cookieUrl = u;
        return this;
    }


    /**
     *
     */
    public Builder setContactsLearnMoreUrl(final String u) {
        contactsLearnMoreUrl = u;
        return this;
    }

}
```

Any idea why I can't access this class from the main project?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the class there when you decompile the APK (not just the AAR) as well, or just view it in Android Studio? Are any other classes in the same package using this class? By not being able to access the class, do you mean that the other project does not compile when you try to use it / autocomplete doesn't work / searching for the class with double-tap on the shift key doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, if I decompile the aar (rename aar to zip, unzip, open the class.jar file) this specific class is there. Autocomplete works with other classes inside the aar, but not the `Builder` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After randomly working then not working, it appears that a `File -> Invalidate caches / restart` in Android Studio did the trick.

So apparently Android Studio caches some part of the aar, which even a `Clean` nor `Rebuild` would fix.

Comment: I am not able to fix this.
I imported an aar file as a dependency and want to call a function from the class.
but the class is not found.
could you please help

Answer (score 2):

Hi did you check your dependencies? if it was added in there? what i meant is this one [image] Also refer to this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies) for the difference between implementation and api.

Comment: Yes, I've added it to my dependencies. I'm able to access other classes in the same package.. just not the Builder class.